# Do the spaces spanned by the columns of a matrix and by the columns of a set of matrices coincide?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, solution-verification

> As in
>   [Do the spaces spanned by the columns of the given matrices coincide?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1293755/do-the-spaces-spanned-by-the-columns-of-the-given-matrices-coincide),
>   let $$A = \begin{pmatrix}  1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\  1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\  0 & 0 &
>  1 & 0 \\  0 & 0 & 1 & 1  \end{pmatrix}\text{.}$$ Define $$K =
>  \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1
>  \end{pmatrix}, L = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 0
>  \\ 1 & 0 & 1  \end{pmatrix}, F = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 5 & 6 \\ 1 & 5 &
>  6 \\ 0 & 7 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 9 \end{pmatrix}, D = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0
>  \\ 1 & 0 \\ 2 & 5 \\ 0 & 0  \end{pmatrix},$$$$ G = \begin{pmatrix} 1 &
>  0 & 5 & 2 \\ 1 & 0 & 5 & 2 \\ 2 & 5 & 7 & 9 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 
>  \end{pmatrix}\text{.}$$
>   Is the space spanned by the columns of $A$ the same as the space spanned by the columns of $K, L, F, D,$ and $G$?

My answer: **Yes**. If we were to take a linear combination of the columns of the above matrices (excluding $A$), the first two components starting from the top of the column vector would be identical. Hence any vector in the space spanned by the columns of $K, L, F, D,$ and $G$ can be written in the form $(a, a, b, c)^{\prime}$, identical form to a vector in $C(A)$, as I demonstrated in the linked question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method**

A relatively easy way to prove it would be to column reduce (or take the transpose and row reduce, if you prefer) each of these matrices and see if their reduced column echelon form (or reduced row echelon form if you transposed first) of each has exactly the same nonzero columns.

Or you can use your method -- finding the conditions on an arbitrary element of the column spaces of each one by looking at linear combinations of the columns.  It's pretty easy in this case, but sometimes it's harder to see precisely the (in)dependence of the components of the arbitrary vector in the space.

**Hint**

I can tell you at least one of those matrices has a different column space than the rest.  Try to figure out which one(s).