# Find a matrix whose column space contains the column space of the given matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, solution-verification

> Let $$A = \begin{pmatrix}  1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\  1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\  0 & 0 &
>  1 & 0 \\  0 & 0 & 1 & 1  \end{pmatrix}\text{.}$$ $C(A)$ denotes the
>   column space of $A$. Give a matrix whose column space contains $C(A)$.

My solution: Let $$A^{*} = \left(\begin{array}{c|c}
 & 0 \\
A & 1\\
 & 0\\
 & 0
\end{array}\right)\text{.}$$
Then any vector in $C(A^*)$ is in the form $(a, b, c, d)^{\prime}$, all in $\mathbf{R}$. With $b = a$, we have $C(A^{*}) = C(A)$ ([as shown previously](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1293755/do-the-spaces-spanned-by-the-columns-of-the-given-matrices-coincide)), so $C(A) \subset C(A^*)$.

Comment: Easier: the same matrix as $\;A\;$ *without the first column* ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your answer is correct.

You could also just substitute the vector $e_2$ to the first column, because $\text{rank}(A)=3<4$: this implies that the first vector does not augment the dimension of the column space.